# Can a mail-sending program send mails under my email?

Tags: security, email, smtp

I'm new to SMTP techniques so with just a few days work with it, I have this question - Can a mail-sending program send mails under my email?

It seems like I can put any email in to `from` field and if I put my friend's email there, I can disguise him!? This sound strange since I believe that being some one else is not that ease at all.

Please guide me if you have experiences on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any email client can send an email using ANY email address as the from field.

That said, a lot of receiving mail servers are configured to do various tests to ensure that the email is coming from a real mail server.

For a list of those techniques used by receiving mail servers go here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-spam_techniques  Specifically the "automated techniques for e-mail administrators" section.

A short list from there is:
1. **Reverse DNS -** tests the IP address of the sender to ensure that the IP is listed as an MX record for the domain.
2. **FCrDNS -** receiving mail server will attempt to do an SMTP HELO or EHLO command back to the sender's IP.  This makes sure the sender is an SMTP server.
3. **Disallow Dynamic IPs** - receiving server will test the sender's IP to see if it is DHCP'd.  If so, then the mail is marked as spam.

Point is, you *can* send email as being originated from any email address.  However, there is a huge possibility that the email will simply be deleted by the receiving server.

Comment: An existing account check doesn't validate that the mail actually came from it.  The ol' telnet & getting mail from billgates@microsoft trick, for example...

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I actually meant to say "real server" as opposed to "real account"  You're right, tests to see if there is such an account on an existing server don't do much to ensure that the message came from that person.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can do what you say with an email client like *Thunderbird* where you can set the From address freely.

Anyway, you will need a SMTP server that will accept this *any domain* address (your provider SMTP will probably do).

That's also why some SMTP servers (like Gmail's one for instance) force the user to get athenticated and displays his user adress (it will sometimes display *on behalf of* when sending from another e-mail address. This is very well explained on [Google site](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/07/send-mail-from-another-address-without.html).

Regards,

Max